# How to fix make file circular dependency?

Tags: makefile

I am using this tool called RNAEditingIndexer here is the link to make file

https://github.com/a2iEditing/RNAEditingIndexer/tree/master/make

it goes into a circular dependency error and gets stuck following is what I am getting

```
    (base) ayeshatariq@Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro ~ % conda activate py27
(py27) ayeshatariq@Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro ~ % cd ~/Desktop/RNAEditingIndexer 
(py27) ayeshatariq@Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro RNAEditingIndexer % . ./configure.sh
./configure.sh:2: no such file or directory: \nThis work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Non-Commercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International License.\nTo view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/.\nFor use of the software by commercial entities, please inquire with Tel Aviv University at ramot@ramot.org.\n(c) 2019 Tel Aviv University (Erez Y. Levanon, Erez.Levanon@biu.ac.il;\nEli Eisenberg, elieis@post.tau.ac.il;\nShalom Hillel Roth, shalomhillel.roth@live.biu.ac.il).\n
BEDTools Path Executable Test - Succeeded
BEDTools Version Test - Succeeded
SAMTools Path Executable Test - Succeeded
SAMTools Version Test - Succeeded
BAM Utils Path Executable Test - Succeeded
BAM Utils Run Test - Succeeded
BAM Utils Version Test - Succeeded
Java Path Executable Test - Succeeded
Java Run Test - Succeeded (java.version = 19.0.1)
Python 2.7 Path Executable Test - Succeeded
Python 2.7 Version Test - Succeeded
(py27) ayeshatariq@Ayeshas-MacBook-Pro RNAEditingIndexer % make
make: Circular /Users/ayeshatariq/Desktop/RNAEditingIndexer/make/Makefile <- /Users/ayeshatariq/Desktop/RNAEditingIndexer/make/Makefile dependency dropped.
/Users/ayeshatariq/Desktop/RNAEditingIndexer/obj/EditingIndexJavaUtils/BEDGenomeIndexer.class.
```

can anybody help with that?

I tried adding a OUT=foo command but it didn't resolve it

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the formatting so the output is a code block, instead of a re-wrapped blob of text.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to not use the really old version of GNU Make that Apple ships.  Use MacPorts or similar to get a more recent version of GNU Make that has better behaviors and doesn't have Apple patches applied.

Comment: But, just to note, this is not technically an error, in that GNU Make doesn't stop processing.  GNU Make will drop the circular dependency and continue on to do whatever it was going to do anyway.

Comment: The diagnostic message seems to be saying that the dependency this is dropped is the makefile depending on itself.  This probably reflects an error in the makefile, but in and of itself, `make`'s resolution seems reasonable.

Comment: @MadScientist I did not get any error but the processing was stuck at JavaUtils/BEDGenomeIndexer.class for hours? Do you think using Macports will fix it?

Comment: No.  It's not a problem with make.  Make invoked the command that your makefile asked it to, and make is waiting for that command to finish.  If it doesn't finish, there's nothing make can do about that.  The problem is we have no idea what command make invoked.  It's highly unlikely that `/Users/ayeshatariq/Desktop/RNAEditingIndexer/obj/EditingIndexJavaUtils/BEDGenomeIndexer.class.` is a command.  This means that the makefile has hidden the actual command.  If you had a newer version of GNU make, you could use the `make --trace` option to have make show you the command it invoked.

Comment: In the version of make you have, you can try running `make -n` which might work, else you'll have to run `make -d` and wade through the output to find the command that was invoked.  Or else, look in the makefile to find the rule that invoked this command and remove the `@` characters from the beginning of the recipe lines or comment out the `.SILENT:` pseudo-target.  See the GNU Make manual to learn about all these things.

Comment: Thank you for all the help I really appreciate that.